# Center tick labels and add labels beside colorbar extensions in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am looking for solutions to:

1. Align vertically the tick labels along the colorbar with the center of each color/class.
2. Place some tick labels beside both colorbar triangular extensions.
3. Change the figure size to see the tick labels completely while keeping the same colorbar width.

I already tried various solutions proposed on stack overflow to center the tick labels, but none seems to work properly with my current code. For exemple, using `ax.set_yticks(number_of_classes + 0.5)` or other similiar methods put all the tick labels at the bottom of the colorbar instead of placing them aligned with the center of each color.

[This is the colorbar I get with my current code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDmw7.png)

Here's the code I used:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

# data and labels
bounds = [44, 51, 53, 56]
color_palette = [[43, 131, 186],
                 [86, 104, 146],
                 [129, 78, 107],
                 [172, 51, 67],
                 [215, 25, 28]]
tick_labels = ['Convection not likely',
               'Likely thunderstorms',
               'Isolated severe storms',
               'Widely scattered severe storms',
               'Scattered severe storms']

# Array of colors with rgb value in 0-1 range
all_vals = np.array([[color_palette[0][0] / 255,
                      color_palette[0][1] / 255,
                      color_palette[0][2] / 255,
                      1]])

for i in range(1, len(color_palette)):
    vals = [[color_palette[i][0] / 255,
             color_palette[i][1] / 255,
             color_palette[i][2] / 255,
             1]]
    all_vals = np.concatenate((all_vals, vals))

# create a colormap
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(all_vals[1:-1])
cmap.set_over(all_vals[-1])
cmap.set_under(all_vals[0])

# normalize bound values
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# create a figure
fig = Figure(figsize=(2, 6))
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)

# create the colorbar
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                               norm=norm,
                               extend='both',
                               ticks=bounds,
                               spacing='uniform')

# add the tick labels
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels)

fig.savefig('colorbar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting ticklabels, it is important to also set the tick positions. For the colorbar, these positions need to be set with `cb.set_ticks` (this is confusing, as the labels need to be set via `cb.ax.set_yticklabels`). Tick positions can only be set at the extremes of the main colorbar, not exactly near the extensions.

So, logical positions are: one at the very bottom, one at the very top, and in the middle of the subsequent `bounds`. The label at the bottom can be top-aligned to set it closer to the downward triangle (and similar for the upward triangle).

As the labels now indicate a region, the ticks marks could be removed.

```py
cb.set_ticks([bounds[0]] + [(b0 + b1) / 2 for b0, b1 in zip(bounds[:-1], bounds[1:])] + [bounds[-1]])
tick_texts = cb.ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels)
tick_texts[0].set_verticalalignment('top')
tick_texts[-1].set_verticalalignment('bottom')
cb.ax.tick_params(length=0) # optionally remove the tick marks
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To create a figure and axes, usually the simplest way is leaving out `FigureCanvasAgg` and creating figure and axes via `plt.subplots()`.  The 'left' and 'right' padding (white space left and right of the axes' rectangle) can be set via `gridspec_kw`.  You can still save an image via `fig.savefig`. With `plt.show()` you get a window where these paddings can be changed interactively.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 5), gridspec_kw={'left': .4, 'right': .5})
# ...
fig.savefig(...)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I would also like to know how do you resize the figure to see the entire labels as in the picture you posted without changing the colorbar size. When I try to widen the figure to make everything fit by changing the `figsize`,  it also increases the colorbar width.